# Unable to get local issuer certificate mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, openssl, macos-big-sur

Running a simple request on Python3.9 on Mac OS BigSur, I'm getting this error:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='store.immediasys.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))

```
import requests
try:
    t = requests.get("https://store.immediasys.com/")
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

I've tried ran the Install Certificates in the Python3.9 folder and I already have certifi installed and updated. Any help with this? It happens on different websites.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate of this web-site is signed by `Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA`. Your Python installation misses this certificate. Download it from [Sectigo web site](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000rfBO) and add to Python certificates.

The path to your certificates: `python -m certifi`
Just append the downloaded certificate to that file. Please note that you might have to append this certificate to the CRT file each time you update `certifi`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pak, the problem is; I'm getting this issued with several websites, I'm wondering if there is a larger solution.

Comment: @AlexandreCavalcante, the *larger* solution is to force Mozilla to include this certificate into their list of trusted CAs, since `cetifi` uses Mozilla's database.

Comment: Actually, the larger problem that @AlexandreCavalcante is referring to, is that after using the mac installer from python.org, the newly installed version of Python is unable to find the system certificates. When running `ssl.create_default_context().cert_store_stats()` you'll likely see there are 0 certificates. I've raised an issue for this at: https://bugs.python.org/issue43404?@ok_message=msg%20388123%20created%0Aissue%2043404%20created&@template=item

Comment: So, larger solution turns out to be: RTM. :P
At the end of the installer it says to run some certificates.command file in order to install a reasonable set of certificates.

Answer (score 1):

The Read Me.rtf for Mac python binaries from python.org states the following:

> This variant of Python 3.7 includes its own private copy of OpenSSL
> 1.1.1.  The deprecated Apple-supplied OpenSSL libraries are no longer used.  This means that the trust certificates in system and user
> keychains managed by the Keychain Access application and the security
> command line utility are no longer used as defaults by the Python ssl
> module.  A sample command script is included in /Applications/Python
> 3.7 to install a curated bundle of default root certificates from the third-party certifi package.

I had this problem, too, and after running the script (called `Install Certificates.command`), everything worked perfectly and I stopped getting the error.

Hat tip to @SamBull in the comments for pointing it out.